# Holiday calendar with php mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, calendar

I need to customized the calendar with php mysql.

In mysql I have created the holiday master and in front end holidays date of calendar should be disabled and rest of the dates should be available to select date.

Kindly let me know how I can proceed through this problem, if any more information needed let me know.

Comment: Some code with a specific problem is needed on SO...

Comment: I have just started this application i haven't any idea how to proceed

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

Comment: This is the date picker i need the calender in which i can manage the different events.

Comment: Well that's the thing you should starting to code then... sorry but we can't help you if you have nothing.

Comment: Take a look at my github repo [jQuery FullCalendar CRUD](https://github.com/tliokos/jquery-fullcalendar-crud). I think it will help you get started.